# my action is called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action to return a page's PageRank. When I debug my site and call that action first my action is called with the url and it return the page's PR and then it's called again with no url and that throws an exception. I don't know why that happening.

this is my Action

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public string PR(string id)
{
    Uri u = new UriBuilder(id).Uri;
    id = u.AbsoluteUri;
    return GooglePageRank.PRChecker.PR(id);
}
```

I'm using IIS8 Express and .Net 4.5 but it's same with IIS7.5 and .Net 4

Comment: Maybe there's something in the rendered page (some JavaScript or a page resource) which is calling the current resource?  Do you have a live example of this happening?  Check the network panel in your browser debugger to see if there are clues in there.  Trying to reproduce the problem on another page might narrow it down as well.

Comment: @David it just return the PageRank as number. It's string action so it isn't use any other layout or JS codes!

Comment: From the browser's debugger, is there an actual second call to the action method?  Is there code in the application which manually invokes the action method?

Comment: @David how can I find that if there is any second call to the action method? I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Add breakpoint on Any xhr request

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chrome's debugging tools, but there should be a feature somewhere in there for monitoring network requests and responses.  For server-side calls, you can just look for references to that function.

Answer (score 2):

I used fiddler and found that It's happening because of [Web Server Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-notifier/najdkmbedaehkepolllmpdfccdgooajh) and [Web Technology Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-technology-notifier/fnpgnmindcbkjbpblcklealdhnogmlko) extensions of chrome and they send another requests to the action.